# Python function compatible with sync and async client

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm developing a library that should support sync and async users while minimizing code duplication inside the library. The ideal case would be implementing the library async (since the library does remote API calls) and adding support for sync with a wrapper or so. Consider the following function as part of the library.

```py
# Library code

async def internal_function():
  """Internal part of my library doing HTTP call"""
  pass
```

My idea was to provide a wrapper that detects if the users of the library use async or not.

```py
# Library code

def api_call():
   """Public api of my library"""
    if asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():
        # Async caller
        return internal_function()  # This returns a coroutine, so the caller needs to await it
    
    # Sync caller, so we need to run the coroutine in a blocking way
    return asyncio.run(internal_function())
```

At first, this seemed to be the solution. With this I can support

- users that call the function from an async function,
- users that call the function from a notebook (that's also async), and
- users that call the function from a plain python script (here it falls back to the blocking `asyncio.run`).

However, there are cases when the function is called from within an event loop, but the direct caller is a sync function.

```py
# Code from users of the library

async def entrypoint():
    """This entrypoint is called in an event loop, e.g. within fastlib"""
    return legacy_sync_code()  # Call to sync function

def legacy_sync_code():
    """Legacy code that does not support async"""
    # Call to library code from sync function,
    # expect value not coroutine, could not use await
    api_response = api_call()
    return api_response.json()  # Needs to be value, not coroutine
```

In the last line, the call of `json()` fails. `api_call()` wrongly inferrs that the caller can await the response, and returns the coroutine.

In order to support these kind of users, I would need to

- identify if the direct calling function is sync and expects a value instead of a corouting,
- have a way to await the result of `internal_function()` in a blocking way. Using `asyncio.run` does only work in plain python scripts and fails if the code was called form an event loop higher up in the stack trace.

The first point could be mitigated if my library provided two functions, e.g., `api_call_async()` and `api_call_sync()`.

I hope I make my point clear enough. I don't see why this should be fundamentally impossible, however, I can accept if the design of Python does not allow me to support sync and async users in a completely transparent way.

Comment: Fundamentally, what you are asking is futile in Python, because you will need to baby this for each and every method of the return type - I assume the `json()` is a method that can be called by whatever returned by the `internal_function()`, this part isn't clear - you will also need to wrap that function with your wrapper and this is just a futile way to approach this and it adds unnecessary overhead.  Just stick with providing async and sync version.

Comment: Calling async from sync is bad design: https://discuss.python.org/t/calling-coroutines-from-sync-code/23027

Comment: ... Yes? I thought that's what you were trying to do with that detection attempt with that `api_call()` wrapper? So don't do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not try to be too flexible or solve problems that yet not occurred. That would make your life harder and potentially your code more complex to develop and maintain and in result not really that flexible as you'd have thought. It's nothing wrong to not babysit fellow developers and let them take some bit of responsibility. Let them make own choice if they want to go sync or async. Also note, that what can appear benefit for you (in terms of implementation details etc, like detecting sync/async), may be a deal breaker for others as you might be doing something you weren't asked for in the first place. It's easy to outsmart yourself for no real benefit and then waste lot of time fixing problems you just happily created. I personally would go for separate `api_call_sync()` and `api_call_async()` approach but also ensure my library documentation is dumb-clear and discuss all the edge cases you right now think of as being potentially problematic, so my users got full picture of the battlefield to take the best shot they can.